# TweenLite js not animating height

Tags: jquery, gsap

I just tried out TweenLite and I'm going nuts as I have copied the code from the site but I can't get it to animate.

CSS

```
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

html

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

JS

```
   setTimeout(function(){
        var target = $('.box');
        console.log("box = ", target);
        TweenLite.to(target, 1, {css:{height:"0px"}});
    },2000);
```

Also tried no css.

```
   setTimeout(function(){
        var target = $('.box');
        console.log("box = ", target);
        TweenLite.to(target, 1, {height:0});
    },2000);
```

And yes I have the JS in a jquery document ready method. I also have the TweenLite.js loaded.
Anyone know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what's happening with your setup, but the code works fine for me. Here's a codepen:

http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/9e7c951949caa10b928d929378947f01

I simplified the code a bit too, although the long-hand style you used was fine. You don't need to use a setTimeout() to delay the start - just use the "delay" special property.

```
TweenLite.to(".box", 1, {height:0, delay:2});
```

I wonder if maybe either jQuery or the GreenSock JavaScript files aren't loading in your particular setup. If you're still having trouble, please post a link to a simple codepen or jsfiddle and we'll take a peek.

Comment: Issue was that I needed to load the cssPlugin in order to get TweenLite.to(target, 1, {css:{height:"0px"}}); to work. Thanks for replying to the answer